# Multiple conditions in assert

Tags: python, pytest, assert

Can we have multiple conditions in a single assertIn statement?

For ex:

```
self.assertIn('dns', body, 'Querying failed')
```

But the body contains both `dns` as well as `dns_cache_expire_time`. Is there a way to put both of them in the same `assertIn` statement so that I can check if both the objects are present in the body?

Thanks!!

Comment: If the body contains `dns_cache_expire_time` then it also contains `dns`, so there's no point in testing them both.

Comment: What is `assertIn()`? It's not in the pytest documentation.

Comment: do you have any unittest import in your code?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn